# Android RadioButton not centering

Tags: android, center, centering, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I have the following RadioButtons:

[image]

They are generated programmatically in this method:

```
 private void initializeAbilityComponents() {
    rgAbility = view.findViewById(R.id.rgAbility);

    for (int i = 0; i < abilities.size(); i++) {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(4,4,4,4);
        radioButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        radioButton.setText(abilities.get(i).getName());
        radioButton.setId(i);
        radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        PokemonUtils.setRoundedBackgroundColorToView(radioButton,selectedPokemon.getColor());
        rgAbility.addView(radioButton);
    }
```

And added to this xml RadioGroup:

```
  <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rgAbility"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layoutAnimation="@anim/default_layout_right_to_left_animation"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
```

However , as you can see , they are not really centered , the output I expect when I center is this :

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: You want the dots at the center? if you can share all the code

Comment: No, I want the dots to remain at start , I only want the text to be really centered as my last image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add:

```
radioButton.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
radioButton.setPadding(0,0,100,0); //left, top, right, bottom
```

With the value 100 for right you move your text to the left

Answer (score 1):

This happens because both dot and text are the part of the view. If you want the text be "more centered", you have to add `paddingEnd`. Of course this padding depends on the size of the dot.

Comment: add padding end to radio group or radio button?

Comment: Add it to RadioButton